# Advantage of create ASP.NET MVC project with WebForm core reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

The 'New ASP.NET Project' dialog lets you create an MVC Project, and allows you to add a 'core reference' to Web Forms.

What is the advantage and usage of adding the WebForms reference?

Is it so the web project can contain both MVC views and controllers as well as WebForms pages?

[image: Add Web Forms core reference to new MVC project]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it so the web project can contain both MVC views and controllers as well as WebForms pages?

Indeed. And if you check Web API, you can even create `ApiController`-derived controllers.

Sometimes you want to use multiple techniques in a single project. If you don't need it: don't check it. You can always add it manually when required later.

Comment: thanks you for answer. In additional, finally i find a blog explain this. http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2013-oct-17-vs.aspx